# how to customize react-toastify

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-toastify

I need to customize react-toastify.

I tried to follow the advice from the documentation and change the styles in the .scss file. unfortunately this didn't work. tell me what am I doing wrong?
I want notifications to look like on the picture [how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ4Kj.png)

Comment: You should share the corresponding part of your code so we can check it out and tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in `App.js` :

```
   <ToastContainer
       position="bottom-right"
       autoClose={8000}
       pauseOnHover={true}
       draggable={true}
       theme="dark"
    />
```

here the toast appears on the bottom-right side, it is automatically closed after 8 seconds and its background theme is dark.

Comment: How can I increase the width of the notification and change the colors?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `style` attribute like this:

```
     <ToastContainer
        position="bottom-right"
        autoClose={8000}
        pauseOnHover={true}
        draggable={true}
        theme="dark"
        style={{width: "100px"}}
      />
```